# Solr doesn't start in jetty while installing CKAN

Tags: solr, jetty, ckan

Being asked to install CKAN, I'm following [the documented procedure](http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.7.3/maintaining/installing/install-from-package.html) .
The procedure mentions Ubuntu as the OS, but since I'm on Debian 9 I chose to go ahead anyway.

I managed to install and configure pretty much everything up to solr(3.6.2) on jetty(9.2.21) (the packge is "solr-jetty", jetty can start autonomously binding to its own socket, since the test page of the root application can be seen), but an NPE is thrown and traced into the logs when I start jetty.

The installation creates a file /etc/jetty9/contexts/solr.xml with the following contents:

```xml
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/solr</Set>
  <Set name="war">/usr/share/solr/web</Set>

  <!-- Set the solr.solr.home system property -->
  <Call name="setProperty" class="java.lang.System">
    <Arg type="String">solr.solr.home</Arg>
    <Arg type="String">/usr/share/solr</Arg>
  </Call>

  <!-- Enable symlinks -->
  <Call name="addAliasCheck">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$ApproveSameSuffixAliases"/>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

which I reference from the file /etc/jetty9/jetty.conf

```
jetty-logging.xml
contexts/solr.xml
jetty-started.xml
```

The configuration file for the solr webapp seems to be correctly picked up. Also, the property `solr.solr.home` seems to be mapped to a correct directory.
However, when starting jetty, the following content is written in /var/log/jetty9/ :

```
2018-05-02 11:51:00.827:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@5afa04c{/,file:/var/lib/jetty9/webapps/root/,AVAILABLE}{/root}
2018-05-02 11:51:00.853:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@41b12eec{HTTP/1.1}{127.0.0.1:8983}
2018-05-02 11:51:00.853:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @831ms
2018-05-02 11:51:00.853:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@40ef3420{/solr,null,null}{/usr/share/solr/web}
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration$ClassList.serverDefault(Configuration.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.loadConfigurations(WebAppContext.java:932)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:435)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:504)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:321)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:817)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:112)
```

I just can't figure out what is causing the NPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contexts/solr.xml` should not be in your `jetty.conf`

That XML file should be picked up from the `WebAppProvider` that scanning a configured directory location Jetty, which is part of the `DeploymentManager` concepts within Jetty.

They way you have it configured right now, you have a Server with a root context (deployed from `/var/lib/jetty9/webapps/root/`), and a separate object that creates an unconnected `WebAppContext` which isn't attached to a `HandlerCollection`, or a `Context`, or even a `Server`.

Find the `monitoredDirName` directory referenced by `WebAppProvider` and make sure your `solr.xml` is present in that directory.

Tip: locate the `start.ini` (file) or `start.d/*.ini` (dir + files) for the actual jetty configuration you are using.  The `monitoredDirName` is likely to be declared in one of those files on your system.

> Lastly, [Jetty 9.2.x is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-dev/msg02726.html), consider upgrading.

Comment: Thank you Joakim. All I had to do is to link the solr-jetty.xml file in the monitored directory, and it got correctly deployed.

Comment: On a lighter note, the aforementioned procedure for installing CKAN is about installing a bunch of packages altogether. Only afterwards it says to install the only package "solr-jetty". Its installation ultimately fails because solr-jetty depends on "jetty9", whose installation fails, as Jetty tries to bind on port 8080 which is already bounded. I repeated the installation by first installing jetty9, correcting its configuration (binds on port 8983) and then installing solr-jetty. This way the deployment of solr works as expected.

Comment: I never install jetty from linux packaging, as its always so intensely mutilated beyond its intended use case by the linux package maintainers.   I always install Jetty from tarball.

Comment: You are right. As a matter of fact, the package "solr-jetty" lacks some basic scripts, such as the one used to create new cores in solr. At this point I will uninstal the both and start from the archive of a standalone Solr installation.